# Usage of local dart library

Tags: dart

I have created some local libraries in my dart lib directory. 
These libraries are visible in dart packages for each newly created folder in the web directory. However, when I attempt to access them using the dart's package nomenclature eg package:reg/name.dart, the system always generates an error.

I think I am missing something.

I have read http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html but this did not help me either.

Comment: Please add the error you're getting, as well as a small reproducible sample. The more info we have the better we can diagnose your problem.

Comment: Solved. I found out what to do. Thanks.

Comment: If you have figured out the problem, please post the solution below so that everyone can use your knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the name you're using as the package matches that in pubspec.yaml.

Eg. if in pubspec.yaml you have`name: my_app` and your file is at `lib\my_library.dart` then you need to use `import 'package:my_app/my_library.dart';`.