# referencing local dart libraries

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I am writing 4 dart libraries A, B, C, and D and they are all early in development so I don't want to publish them on pub yet.

It is also the case that only A, B and C are public libraries which all depend on D which should be private to just those three libraries. How Do I manage a situation like this?

Can I use pub to install library D for A, B and C on my local development machine whilst it isn't published? and how do I publish A, B and C when they are complete without publishing D, seen as D is not particularly useful if it isn't being used by A, B or C?

I have read the [getting started guide](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/) and [package structure](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html) documentation but neither seemed to cover this type of situation, i.e. how to manage private libraries. There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642502/usage-of-local-dart-library) SO question but the user didn't answer it after resolving her issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, dependencies resolve to Pub but you can override that to import packages from URLs, git and local path.

For instance, the following is the syntax for importing a local package:

```
dependencies:
  transmogrify:
    path: /Users/me/transmogrify
```

See [Pub Dependencies](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html) for more info.

As far as the other part of your question, I don't see how A, B, and C can logically be public packages and rely on a private package. I would publish all of the packages and just include in the description of D that is not meant as a standalone package and is only intended as a helper package for A, B, and C.

You could also publish A, B, and C to Pub and host D on github or a public URL and specify the relevant URL dependency in the pubspec for A, B, and C (see the above link for the proper syntax). This might make the differentiation between D and the other libraries a bit clearer, though in practice they will all still be publicly available packages.

Comment: For people like me who use the editor's GUI to edit the pubspec.yaml, it's the dropdown "Source" under "Dependency Details". Add dependency, select "Path", enter path, save.